# fluent nhibernate configuration not working

Tags: c#, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

Solved: ClassMap when configuration in code, ClassMapping when configuration in config file, but mapping in code.

When trying to save an object of type Object1 to my database I get the error:

> No persister for: Object1.

Class definition:

```
public class Object1
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastModified { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Other Reference { get; set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
public class Object1Mapping : ClassMapping<Object1>
{
    public Object1Mapping()
    {
        Id(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Created);
        Property(p => p.LastModified);
        ManyToOne(p => p.Reference, m => m.Cascade(Cascade.Remove));
    }
}
```

Configuration code:

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
        .ConnectionString(c => c
            .Server("serverUrl")
            .Database("myMsSqlDatabase")
            .Username("sa")
            .Password("pasword1")))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
        .AddFromAssemblyOf<Object1Mapping>()
        .AddFromAssemblyOf<Object1>()
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

All my classes are public and I added an `AddFromAssemblyOf` for every class that needs a persister. Also I tried both adding the classes themselves and the mapping classes. I know that one `AddFromAssembly` should be enough as should add all mapping classes from that assembly and all my mapping classes are in one project in one folder.

I managed to run diagnostics and it's looking through the correct Assembly, but it discovered no mappings, here is the result:

> ### Fluent Mappings
>
> Sources scanned:
>
> Project.DomainModel.NHibernate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null
>
> Mappings discovered:
>
> None found
>
> ### Conventions
>
> Sources scanned:
>
> None found
>
> ### Automapping
>
> Skipped types:
>
> None found
>
> Candidate types:
>
> None found

I've read tons of documentation and questions, it seems I'm missing something really obvious :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All different mapping types (by code, fluent, automapping, xml...) are supported by `Fluently.Configure`. It just needs different kind of code snippet to add it to your configuration.

Here are some different ways to add mappings to your configuration via `Fluently` configuration

```
.Mappings(m =>
{
    foreach (var assembly in MapAssemblies)
    {
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
        m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
        m.AutoMappings.Add(..)
    }    
})
```

...

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => {
    foreach (var assembly in MapAssemblies)
    {
        cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMappingHelper.GetMappings(assembly), null);
        cfg.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    }
```

The above used helper class:

```
public class HbmMappingHelper
{
    public static HbmMapping GetMappings(Type[] types)
    {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetExportedTypes());
        }

        return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
    }

    public static HbmMapping GetMappings(Assembly assembly)
    {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.AddMappings(assembly.GetExportedTypes());

        return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I could have used my old mapping files without converting if I had used 'AutoMappings' instead of 'FluentMappings'. Even so I like the FluentMappings better.

Answer (score 2):

I think except to add all the mapping by foreach, you can do this.

```
 .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings
                   .AddFromAssemblyOf<Your_Class_For_Fluent_Configuration>()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that to use mappings in FluentNHibernate you need different mappings than are used when configuring NHibernate from a config file. ClassMapping originates from NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist and ClassMap (found in code examples) originates from FluentNHibernate.Mapping

Tested this and it solves this problem, so changing the inheriting class from `ClassMapping` to `ClassMap` allowed the fluent configuration to find my mapping.

Comment: the answer is actually wrong because you can use Fluent Nhibernate `Fluently.Configure()` with any kind of mapping

Comment: @MichaC Great! Please tell me how. Even so this answer is usefull because it solves my problem. Please don't downvote so easily, I never stated explicitly that NHibernate requires mappings.