# nHiberanate 3.0 + Fluent nHiberanate : "No Persister for:" Error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
public class PersonEntity
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string MobilePhone { get; set; }

}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<PersonEntity>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("People");

        Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.FirstName, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.LastName, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Email, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.Phone, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.MobilePhone);


    }
}
```

both classes are in the same assembly

```
   public ISessionFactory CreateSF()
    {
        FluentConfiguration fCfg = Fluently.Configure().
                                           Database(                                                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(                                          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eDb"].ConnectionString).ShowSql());


        fCfg.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMap>());
        return fCfg.BuildSessionFactory();

    }
```

and my unit test

```
        var sf = CreateSF();
        using (var _session = sf.OpenSession())
        {

            new PersistenceSpecification<PersonEntity>(_session)
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Id, 1)
                .CheckProperty(x => x.FirstName, "FName")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.LastName, "LName")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.MobilePhone, "12345")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Phone, "987654")
                .CheckProperty(x => x.Email, "email1@email.com")
                .VerifyTheMappings();
        }
```

is throwing the exception

NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for: Ers.Data.PersonEntity
   a

I am Using Nhibernate 3.3.3.
FluentNHibernate 1.4.0.0

is there another way of fixing it? I already have my fluent mappings specified.

Do I miss anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fluent nhibernate configuration not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190857/fluent-nhibernate-configuration-not-working)

Comment: **Why -1?** Because OP did mistake? and is asking here for **help**? That really does not make sense to me. I do balance it here: +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really interesting issue. Nice one... So, do you know what?

- the mapping is for `mapping-by-code`
- the configuration is for `fluent-nhibernate`

Check the comparison and difference here [NHibernate's Mapping by Code](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html)

Other words, just use the [fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping), and configuration will find it... that's it

An example of the fluent mapping

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<PersonEntity>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("People");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Property(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable();
        Property(x => x.LastName).Not.Nullable();
        Property(x => x.Email).Not.Nullable();
        Property(x => x.Phone).Not.Nullable();
        Property(x => x.MobilePhone);
    }
```

There are really very nice links, describing the `mapping-by-code`, BUT honestly, these are **the best source of the fluent mapping** *(always at the bottom of the article)*

- [Id mapping](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html)
- [Property mapping](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html)
- [... overview, with other great features](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html)

Comment: yes, that's the thing. I should just use ClassMap not CLassMapping. got them generated by a tool :( didn't notice , late night coding has it's issues

Comment: @Dorin, I've extended my answer with few adjustments, following the `fluent-mapping`. Also I appended few really cool links with more details. Finally, just if I can give you an advice..., never mix mapping! Think about the future and maintainace ;) Good luck with NHibernate, awesome tool

Comment: @RadimKöhler thats not 100% correct. You can of course use Fluently configuration with any kind of mapping you want. xml mappings, auto-mappings, conformist (by code), attributes or fluent mappings. It is  very easy to configure nhibernate with the fluent stuff but this doesn't restrict you on fluent mappings. And it really makes no difference of which type of mapping you use, it is just the mapping...

Answer (score 0):

As Radim already said, you are writing by code mappings and within the creation of the session factory you only add fluent mappings.

As I've answered in another thread, you can use mappings by code or any other kind of mapping together with `Fluently` configuration.

It is even more not an issue to mix different mapping types! You do not have to rewrite them!

For nhibernate it doesn't matter where the mappings are coming from, at the end it just loads the mapping at startup once and then simply uses configuration objects internally which have been created based on the mappings...

Here are some different ways to add mappings to your configuration via `Fluently` configuration

```
.Mappings(m =>
{
    foreach (var assembly in MapAssemblies)
    {
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
        m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
        m.AutoMappings.Add(..)
    }    
})
```

...

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => {
    foreach (var assembly in MapAssemblies)
    {
        cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMappingHelper.GetMappings(assembly), null);
        cfg.AddInputStream(NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    }
```

The above used helper class:

```
public class HbmMappingHelper
{
    public static HbmMapping GetMappings(Type[] types)
    {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetExportedTypes());
        }

        return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
    }

    public static HbmMapping GetMappings(Assembly assembly)
    {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.AddMappings(assembly.GetExportedTypes());

        return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
    }
}
```